# Why cannot I see the print statements even tho the code is compiling and not showing any errors

Tags: octave

Consider this code:

% DTF vs FFT

```
%% Example 1 N = 64
close all
clear
clc

eval_dft_vs_fft(64);


%% Example 2 N = 512
close all
clear

eval_dft_vs_fft(512);


%% Example 3 N = 4096
close all
clear

eval_dft_vs_fft(4096);


function [t_DFT,t_FFT, RMSE_FFT, RMSE_DFT] = eval_dft_vs_fft(N)
    % generate a arrray of random, complex numbers
    x = complex(rand(1, N), rand(1,N));
    
    tic % begin time measurement for the DFT calculation
    
     
    x_DFT = IDFT(DFT(x));   % Determine the DFT and IDFT result
    
    t_DFT = toc;            % end time measurement
    
    tic                     % begin time measurement for the FFT calculation
    
    x_FFT = ifft(fft(x));   % Determine the FFT and IFFT result
    
    t_FFT = toc;            % end time measurement
    
    % calculate the RMS Error of the DTF
    mean = sum(abs(x - x_DFT).^2)/N;
    RMSE_DFT = sqrt(mean);

    % calculate the RMS Error of the FFT
    mean = sum(abs(x - x_FFT).^2)/N;
    RMSE_FFT = sqrt(mean);
    
    disp("Number of elements N = " + N)
    disp(" ")
    disp("Calculation Time DTF = " + t_DFT)
    disp("Calculation Time FFT = " + t_FFT)
    disp(" ")
    disp("RMS Error DTF = " + RMSE_DFT)
    disp("RMS Error FFT = " + RMSE_FFT)
    fprintf('\n---------------\n\n')
end


function x = IDFT(X)
    
    N = length(X);
    x = zeros(1, N);
    
    for n=0:N-1
        x_1 = 0;
        for k = 0:N-1
            x_1 = x_1 + X(k+1) .* exp((1j*2*pi*k*n)/N);
        end
        x(n+1) = x_1;
    end
    x = x ./ N;

end


function X = DFT(x)

    N = numel(x);
    X = zeros(1, N);

    for k=0:N-1
        X_1 = 0;
        for n = 0:N-1
            X_1 = X_1 + x(n+1) .* exp(-(1j*2*pi*k*n)/N);
        end
        X(k+1) = X_1;
    end

end
```

Its purpose is to compare the calculation time of the DFT and the FFT as well as their RMS error. I am getting no errors in the command window but the disp statements arent showing up anywhere?

Rather what I get in the command window is this;

Columns 1 through 22:

142   181   173   162   165   178    96   175   166    96   165   172   165   173   165   174   180   179    96   142    96   125

61    32

I am very new to Octave so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code?

Comment: I suspect you have a variable, named the same as the script, and thus when calliing the command you are just displaying the variable. Have your script with a different name and it will work.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid octave code. Are you porting code over from matlab by any chance?  (I mean, it will "run", but it probably won't do what you think it's doing ... at least not the _first_ time you run it)

Comment: To expand on what @TasosPapastylianou said, MATLAB changed a few versions ago to allow scripts to contain functions at the end, and they would be available to the script. Previously, and still in Octave, functions always had to be defined before they were used. So in a script, they needed to be at the top. Your script has functions at the end. So it was likely written for Matlab, and in Octave any calls to those functions in the script before the function definition should produce an 'undefined' error.

Comment: error: 'eval_dft_vs_fft' undefined near line 6, column - see the explanation from Nick J above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [disp](https://docs.octave.org/v4.0.0/Terminal-Output.html) does not allow mix text and values. That's the reason why the output are a list of numbers (probably codes os chars or something else). You could separate
`disp("Number of elements N = "), disp(N)` resulting in two lines or use others functions as printf `printf("Number of elements N = %d", N)` to keep text and value in the same line.